# How to force Entity framework saving a specific DateTime precision

Tags: entity-framework, datetime

I would like to force EntityFramework saving dates with only seconds precision.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand You can set your datetime field like this:

```
obj.Field = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

or

```
obj.Field = dateTime.AddTicks( - (dateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
```